# Win10 Default program setting not work

Tags: windows-10, control-panel

A few days ago, I installed win10 LTSC 2019 on a new PC, and when finished installing, I try to set default program (Setting > Default Programs > Set your default programs), but it just  can not take effect, for example, in "web browser" , it lists IE, edge, current selection is IE, I can click mouse and choose edge, but when I release mouse, the selection is still IE, so it just does not change at all, All other programs like "Music Player" "Video Player" the same
phenomenon, strangely, I tested this on another PC which also installed win10 LTSC 2019 a year ago, no such issue, I can change my program settings normally. So Does anybody know why this issue occurred, Thanks

Comment: That is from 4 years ago and IE died and was taken down 2 or more years ago. Get a much newer LTSC version.   Windows 10 is now at 22H2.

Comment: Perform updates for this old version, and IE will disappear.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, Thanks, but IE is not my question's point, I use IE just as an example, what I want to ask is why set default program can not take effect, not just browser, video player also can not change to my choice

Comment: Can you use a newer version of Windows?

Comment: Why are you setting the default application through Control Panel instead of Settings?

Comment: @Ramhound, sorry, I just use setting->default application, not control panel, I made a mistake in my question

Comment: Just a relevant note: LTSC is intended for very limited use cases such as kiosks. It is not intended for any sort of general use, either for private or business purposes.